'Hidden' non white characters in Heinleins work. So racists would identify with them before learning their race
In Heinlein's work many of his characters are non-white or of mixed race. He often does not mention or imply this until well into the book.
In Starship Troopers, it is revealed near the end that Juan Rico speaks Tagalog as his native language, strongly implying he is Filipino:

"Sorry, Bernardo. Just an old saying in my own language. I suppose you could translate it, more or less, as: 'Home is where the heart is.'"
"But what language was it?"
"Tagalog. My native language."
"Don't they talk Standard English where you come from?"
"Oh, certainly. For business and school and so forth. We just talk the old speech around home a little. Traditions. You know."

In The Moon is a Harsh Mistress, Manuel Garcia O Kelly describes his mixed ancestry:

My one grandfather was shipped up from Joburg for armed violence and no work permit, other got transported for subversive activity after Wet Firecracker War. Maternal grandmother claimed she came up in bride ship—but I’ve seen records; she was Peace Corps enrollee (involuntary), which means what you think: juvenile delinquency female type. As she was in early clan marriage (Stone Gang) and shared six husbands with another woman, identity of maternal grandfather open to question. But was often so and I’m content with grandpappy she picked. Other grandmother was Tatar, born near Samarkand, sentenced to "re-education" on Oktyabrakaya Revolyutsiya,

Podkayne of Mars was very proud of being part Maori:

So I grinned back at him and started picking my teeth with a fingernail. This is an even ruder gesture than you might think-and utterly private between Uncle Tom and myself. We Maori have a very bloodthirsty history and I won't even hint at what it is we are supposed to be picking out of our teeth. Uncle Tom used to use this vulgar pantomime on me when I was a little girl, to tell me I wasn't being lady-like.

Rod Walker in Tunnel in the Sky was black but it was only hinted at in the book.
From Heinlein’s "Stealth" Black Character:

That Heinlein created Rod Walker as black was never in doubt; Heinlein scholar Robert James, Ph.D. says "The evidence is slim but definite. First and foremost, outside of the text, there is a letter in which RAH firmly states that Rod is black… RAH often played games with the skin color of his characters, in what I see as a disarming tactic against racists who may come to identify with the hero, then realize later on that they have identified with somebody they supposedly hate."

In one of Heinlein 's long later novels, I do not recall the name of the book, we find out close to the end that the male protagonist is black.
Can you good people name any other examples?

I guess you're ignoring the whole Farnam's Freehold situation?

Farnham's Freehold does not seem to be an example. When they first meet people in the future it is stated immediately that the people driving the vehicles are all black and you very quickly discover they are the rich slave owning people in the future society.

Heinlein said that he meant Farnham 's Freehold to be anti-racist but I am not sure he suceeded.

Yes, that was my point: any attempt to make Heinlein out to be anti-racist is going to struggle very hard to justify it in the face of that book.

The lead character from Glory Road might qualify.  I don't recall how well hidden his ancestry was.

I'll admit that I'm a bit up in the air as to whether this counts as a "list" question. It's probably fairly reasonably constrained.

@FuzzyBoots - the list of works is definitely finite, I don't think there will be new releases from him any time soon! :P

@fez Introducing ChatRAH, aka "Mike", a llm trained on his complete works...

@DanielRoseman - Someone once described it as "an anti-racist novel only a Klansman could love," which seems like an apt description: it wants to say to White Americans, "if you were in the situation that Black people are in, you would see how bad it is," which is not a terrible idea—it's the basic plot of the rather better Noughts and Crosses —but that runs into the problem of Heinlein's book being every paranoid fantasy of Black domination, mixed in with obvious racial stereotypes.

Where Blackman's book has people as people in an oppressive system, Heinlein's has heroic rugged (and sexist) Caucasians versus one-dimensional villainous Africans without any redeeming qualities, with the message being less "oppression is bad regardless of where it originates" and more "if Black people have rights, this is where it will lead." Still, I think the question of whether Heinlein thought one thing or another is largely a temporal one: early-career socialist Heinlein and late-career fascist Heinlein are almost two different people.

This is going to attract a bunch of opinion-based answers too, as well as lots of single list suggestions.

Richard Ames in The Cat Who Walks Through Walls.
There's mention of different skin tone on a replacement leg he was given to fix an old injury as a subtle hint (when we learn who the (clone) donor is, it's a white character), and later in an argument with an explicitly black character with a rather, ah, insensitive name:

It was Little Black Sambo, the sky marshal. "What ticket?"
"The one that entitles you to unscrew the inscrutable. Show it. You are just a lily-livered coward, too yellow to do your plain duty."
"Really? Who appointed you God? Look, boy, I'm mighty glad that your skin color matches mine."
"Why so?"
"Because, if it didn't, I would be called a racist for the way I despise you."


Plus he's apparently very well endowed, which might refer to a certain stereotype.

Yeah, I remember being pretty horrified by the choice of the name for  the other black man he despises.
